# background services for getting activity recognition

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I read a lot about services I tried a lot of examples but unfortunately I couldn't understand how could I keep always services running to get activity recognition API always up and running.

In all cases Android OS killing somehow my running service.

**What I tried:**

I put START_STICKY but when it killed never runs again

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, final int flags, int startId) {
     // my code is here
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

I started service again when I detected that service was killed. It not worked good as expected. I am sending broadcast and starting the service again.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("YouWillNeverKillMe"));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I know about foreground services but in this case there is no way I can use foreground services. I have to forget about this solution.

Is there any other way you can suggest me as a solution? What exactly doing there Facebook or Viber that always I getting messages?

Comment: Use Intent Service with Alarm receiver to run background service permanently after kill application from background too.

Comment: You'll need to provide more code as well as target version(s) of Android in order to get any useful feedback.  On newer versions of Android, the use of non-foreground `Service` components is discouraged in favor of using `JobScheduler` or a high priority FCM (previously called GCM) due to power management.

Comment: @ChiragArora I will try to find an example thank you.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer my minimum API level is 17 its mean I can't use JobScheduler unfortunately.

Comment: If you use `IntentService` then it will *always* be killed after it is done processing the `Intent`.  A `Service` which is not in the foreground can be killed, but should only happen on a device which is under memory/resource pressure or is constrained.  You can mitigate this by using an `Alarm` to trigger a `BroadcastReceiver` which then fires an `Intent` to your service; or, you can try using a `BroadcastReceiver` which is registered for the time update broadcast (though that's not a good practice due to CPU/power usage.)

Comment: @LarrySchiefer you're telling me read this? http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/

Comment: Not necessarily, no.  That page is taking forever to load for me, not sure why.  Here's an article explaining `AlarmManager` to give you a better understanding: http://po.st/7UpipA .It really depends on what your needs are.  Alarms can be used, but they are also falling out of favor and have constraints on newer versions of Android with how often they will run.

Comment: How do you know Android is killing your service? What version of Android are you running on (or testing with)? What device(s)?

Comment: Because it stopping detecting activity recognition until I start the app again